# How to create a choropleth map using mapbox and plotly at a country level?

Tags: python-3.x, mapbox, geo, plotly-python

I am trying to create a choropleth map using plotly and mapbox similar to the US map
https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/ but of African countries. I am new to Python and coding period, so I am a bit lost. My geo data json doesn't have the 'id' field like the the Plotly example. Do I need to create one? Or do I need to just index by df by country? But then how do I match up the instances in the json file? Any help would be appreciated

```
with open('custom.geo.json') as response:
    africa_geo = json.load(response)
data=pd.read_csv('africa_project.csv')
```

[image: data dataframe]

```
africa_geo['features'][0]

{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'scalerank': 0,
  'featurecla': 'Admin-0 country',
  'labelrank': 3,
  'sovereignt': 'Burkina Faso',
  'sov_a3': 'BFA',
  'adm0_dif': 0,
  'level': 2,
  'type': 'Sovereign country',
  'admin': 'Burkina Faso',
  'adm0_a3': 'BFA',
  'geou_dif': 0,
  'geounit': 'Burkina Faso',
  'gu_a3': 'BFA',
  'su_dif': 0,
  'subunit': 'Burkina Faso',
  'su_a3': 'BFA',
  'brk_diff': 0,
  'name': 'Burkina Faso',
  'name_long': 'Burkina Faso',
  'brk_a3': 'BFA',
  'brk_name': 'Burkina Faso',
  'brk_group': None,
  'abbrev': 'B.F.',
  'postal': 'BF',
  'formal_en': 'Burkina Faso',
  'formal_fr': None,
  'note_adm0': None,
  'note_brk': None,
  'name_sort': 'Burkina Faso',
  'name_alt': None,
  'mapcolor7': 2,
  'mapcolor8': 1,
  'mapcolor9': 5,
  'mapcolor13': 11,
  'pop_est': 15746232,
  'gdp_md_est': 17820,
  'pop_year': -99,
  'lastcensus': 2006,
  'gdp_year': -99,
  'economy': '7. Least developed region',
  'income_grp': '5. Low income',
  'wikipedia': -99,
  'fips_10_': 'UV',
  'iso_a2': 'BF',
  'iso_a3': 'BFA',
  'iso_n3': '854',
  'un_a3': '854',
  'wb_a2': 'BF',
  'wb_a3': 'BFA',
  'woe_id': 23424978,
  'woe_id_eh': 23424978,
  'woe_note': 'Exact WOE match as country',
  'adm0_a3_is': 'BFA',
  'adm0_a3_us': 'BFA',
  'adm0_a3_un': -99,
  'adm0_a3_wb': -99,
  'continent': 'Africa',
  'region_un': 'Africa',
  'subregion': 'Western Africa',
  'region_wb': 'Sub-Saharan Africa',
  'name_len': 12,
  'long_len': 12,
  'abbrev_len': 4,
  'tiny': -99,
  'homepart': 1,
  'filename': 'BFA.geojson'},
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[-0.3976712649999, 15.002134501000072],
    [-0.361471923999943, 15.017740784000113],
    [-0.29917598499992, 15.054741110000064],
    [-0.236699177999867, 15.065618999000035],
    [-0.166987670999902, 15.049676819000098],
    [-0.033404092999916, 14.995933329000096],
    [-0.033197387999962, 14.995933329000096],
    [0.218466838000012, 14.910977275000109],
    [0.22084395400006, 14.888213806000126],
    [0.211852254000121, 14.874803772000078],
    ...]]}}
```

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=africa_geo, locations=data.country_name, z=data.ranking,
                                    colorscale="Viridis"))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="dark", mapbox_accesstoken=token,
                  mapbox_zoom=1, mapbox_center = {"lat": 6.6111, "lon": 20.9394})


fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that key is having the "id", a unique identifier called "id". If your geo.json doesn't have that it will not work. Then you have to associate the countries with the unique id and make sure your 'locations' is set equal to the df.id

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had been struggling for ages!

Just to further clarify - each `feature` dictionary in the `features` list has to have an `id` key value pair. You can just create a loop that loops through all the features and makes the `id` key value pair out of a value of `properties`.

Comment: Awesome, I spent countless hours on it myself! I started to lose my mind and then... aha!

Answer (score 2):

In go.Choroplethmapbox you can also point *featureidkey* to the property of geojson that you want to use as id. Say you have country name in your dataframe then you can simply set:

```
go.Choroplethmapbox(...,locations=df["country"],featureidkey="properties.admin", ...)
```